# Line break and also getting space in HL7 message

Tags: hl7

My BizTalk receive XML message as a input message. I am converting that message to HL7 message using Transform in orchestration.
Now if input message consists of any empty field in any of the node, the HL7 message breaks up at that postion and also include space in that message.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? following is my HL7 message:
**Note** --- Copy this message in Textpad to get to know exact space in it

MSH|^~\&|EEHR^bbbbbbbbbb|aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa^12699^DNS|KYIR|CDP|201103060733||VXU^V04|14962|P|2.3.1||||
PID|1||765874316^^^^SS||ssssss^anan^T|wwwww^^^^^^M|20100217|M||2135-2^YYYYYYYY or jjjjjj^HL70005|5896 hyhyhyhy Ave^Apt# 112^Wanta Fe^NM^85678^XXX^H^^049||5033331120X
            ^PRN^PH^^^505^5551120^~^NET^X.400^xxxxxx@yutyutopo.com|5056083515X4365^WPN^PH^^^505^6086715^4365|es^English^HL70296||||215486702|||H^erererer or qwqwqw^HL70189|bnbnbn|Y|1||||

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is - is it that there are spaces in the output HL7 message string?  I'm not on my windows partition right now, so I'm not able to actually see any glaring issues with spacing in your posted message.

Anyway, if it is just spaces, can you just parse through the string and replace spaces in fields with an empty string?

Something like: `message.replaceAll("\\| \\|", "||");` <-- This is Java code

That previous code would replace all instances of '| |' with '||' (i.e. replace fields with a space with an empty string).

Hope that helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is that there are wrong segment separators.
As it would be possible to find just all segment headers as a combination of a blank followed by a known segment header and a field delimiter and to replace the blank by the correct segment separator, there is no guarantee, that you will not get the same combination by chance at a position different from the start of a segment.
So best advice would be to avoid the wrong segment separators und to provide it right.